# Trying to optimize I/O for MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have an updater script that runs every few hours for various regions on a gaming server.  I am looking to run this script more frequently and add more regions.  Ideally I would love to spread the load of the CPU and I/O as evenly as possible.  I used to run this script using mysql, but now the website uses mongodb for everything, so it kinda made sense to move the updater scripts to mongodb too.  I am having really high I/O spikes when mongodb flushes all of the updates to the database.

The script is written in `C#`, although I don't think that's too relative.  More importantly is that we are doing about 500k to 1.2 million updates each time one of these scripts runs.  We have done some small optimizations in the code and with indexes, but at this point we are stuck at how to optimize the actual mongodb settings.

Some other important information is that we do something like this

`update({'someIdentifier':1}, $newDocument)`

instead of this:

`$set : { internalName : 'newName' }`

Not sure if this is a lot worse in performance than doing `$set` or not.

What can we do to try and spread the load out?  I can assign more memory to the VM if that will help as well.

I am happy to provide more information.

Comment: Have you considered throttling the updates?  And are the updates taking more room on the disk?

Comment: NPSF3000 no the updates are not taking up more disk space.  The thing is I want to have the CPU working on mongodb updates almost 100% of the time if possible.  The idea is how to optimize the write ability in mongodb to use less resources and perform faster.  Not sure if there are some settings or not.

Comment: Not off the top of my head, try the monogodb mailing list.  I assume you've considered upgrading hardware?  What is the current performance impact - what does 'I/O Spikes' mean to you?

Comment: I/O Spikes mean 20mbit/s writing for about 5 minutes.  And yeah we have considered upgrading to SSD, but we don't have the money at the moment.

Comment: And this is a problem because.... ?  That's about 750MB of data... how big are your records and how big is the update?

Comment: Errrr, the records are probably 1.2kb each?  Or something close to.  This particular one is about 800,000 rows.  I think it is more like ~1.3gb of data updated maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are my thoughts:

**1)  Properly explain your performance concerns.**

So far I can't really figure out what the issue is or if you have one at all.   As far as I can tell you're doing around a GB of updates and are writing about a GB of data to the disk... not much of a shock.

Oh and do some damn testing - `Not sure if this is a lot worse in performance than doing $set or not.` - why don't you know?  What do your tests say?

**2)  Check to see if there is any hardware mismatch.**

Is your disk just slow?  Is your working set bigger than RAM?

**3)  Ask on mongo-user and other MongoDB specific communities...**

...simply because you might get a better answer there than the lack of answers here.

**4)  Consider trying TokuMX.**

Wait what?  Didn't I just accuse the last guy of suggesting that basically spamming his own product?

Sure, it's a new product that's only been very newly introduced into Mongo (it appears to have a mysql version for a bit longer), but the fundamentals *seem* sound.  In particular it's very good at being *fast* of not only insertions, but updates/deletions.  It does this by not needing to actually go and make the changes to the document in question - but store the insertion/update/deletion message in a buffered queue as part of the index structure.  As the buffer fills up it applies these changes in bulk, which is massively more efficient in terms of I/O.  On top of that, it uses compression in storing data which should additionally reduce I/O - there's physically less to write.

The biggest disadvantage I can see so far is that its best performance is seen with *big* data - if your data fits into RAM than it loses to BTrees in a bunch of tests.  Still fast, but not as fast.

So yeah, it's very new and I would not trust it for anything without testing, and even then only for non-mission-critical stuff, but it *might* be what you're looking for.  And TBH, as it's just a new index/store sub-system... it fits the bill of being an optimisation for mongodb than a separate product.  Especially since index/storage systems in mongodb have always been a bit simple - 'lets use memory-mapped files for caching' etc.